# How to specify the background color of a page?

Tags: wechat-miniprogram

I don't understand how to specify the background color of a given page.

In `app.json`, I have the following:

```
  "window":{
    "backgroundColor": "#ff0000"
  }
```

This color is applied in the very background, I can see it if i try to scroll the page with my finger.

But my views are still *white*.

I tried to simply add the background color of my view and it is mostly working, but the last view is not expanding to the bottom of the screen, so I still have a white area.

How can I either:

- Request all the view to be transparent so that I can see the background color specified in `app.json`
- Create a view which expand to the bottom of the page, without creating a scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `root` element in Wechat Mini-program named `page`.

So the following code will make the work:

```
page
{
  background-color: red;
}
```